# When I use apply function to a single column returns error

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm learning Python and want to use the "apply" function. Reading around the manual I found that if a I have a simple dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 9]] * 3, columns=['A', 'B'])

   A  B
0  4  9
1  4  9
2  4  9
```

and then I use something like this:

```
df.apply(lambda x:x.sum(),axis=0)
```

output works because according to theory x receives every column and apply the sum to each so the the result is correctly this:

```
A    12
B    27
dtype: int64
```

When instead I issue something like:

```
df['A'].apply(lambda x:x.sum())
```

result is: `'int' object has no attribute 'sum'`

question is: why is that working on a dataframe by column, it's ok and working on a single column is not ? In the end the logic should be the same. x should receive in input one column instead of two.

I know that for this simple example I should use other functions like df.agg or even df['A'].sum() but the question is to understand the logic of apply.

Comment: When you use `apply` on Series, the argument is row element in that Series.

Comment: I missed that somewhere in the manual ... :-( thanks !

Comment: @AndreaGrianti note that you should always avoid to use `apply`, here `df.sum()` and `df['A'].sum()` should be used. Always check whether your can use a vectorial alternative and only fallback to `apply` if there is really no other way (`apply` is **slow**).

Comment: Yes I read about that, but considering that I was used to work with for loops which is even slower, apply in general is a step ahead anyway afai can see. but thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Andrea actually, python loops (for or list comprehensions), are usually faster that `apply` ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you look at a specific column of a pandas.DataFrame object, you working with a pandas.Series with (in your case) integers as values. Well and integers don't have a `sum()` method.
(Run `type(df['A'])` to see that you are working with a series and not a data frame anymore when slicing a single column).

The irritating part is that if you work with an actual pandas.DataFrame object, every column is a pandas.Series object and they have a `sum()` method.

So there are two ways to fix your problem

1. Work with a pandas.DataFrame and not with a pandas.Series: `df[['A']]`. The additional brackets force pandas to return a pandas.DataFrame object. (Verify by `type(df[['A']])`) and use the `lambda` function just as you did before
2. use a function rather than a method when using `lambda`: `df['A'].apply(lambda x: np.sum(x))` (assuming that you have imported numpy as `np`)

I would recommend to go with the second option as it seems to me the more generic and clearer way

However, this is only relevant if you want to apply a certain function to ever element in a pandas.Series or pandas.DataFrame. **In your specific case, there is no need to take the detour that your are currently using. Just use** `df.sum(axis=0)`.
The approach with `apply` is over complicating things. The reason why this works is that every element of a pandas.DataFrame is a pandas.Series, which as a `sum` method. But so does a pandas.DataFrame has, so you can use this right away.

The only way, where you actually need to take the way with `apply` is if you had arrays in every cell of the pandas.DataFrame

Comment: I tried your second example with df['A'].apply(lambda x: np.sum(x)) but it returns me just the column and not the sum. In any case the first example works and it's interesting.

Comment: @AndreaGrianti sorry, I focused too much on explaining your "bug". Actually, you don't need the `apply()` method and a `lambda` function. Just use the `sum(axis=0)` method of a pandas.DataFrame =P